# Setting up OrmLite with StructureMap

Tags: c#, asp.net, structuremap, ormlite-servicestack

I want to create a basic IoC of OrmLite with StructureMap but i make something wrong.

At the site of OrmLite they give a simple example how to inject it:

```
container.Register<IDbConnectionFactory>(c => 
    OrmLiteConnectionFactory(":memory:", SqliteDialect.Provider)); //InMemory Sqlite DB
```

So i want to use it in my newly created WebAPI2 application with StructureMap.

I have installed StructureMap.WebAPI2 nuget and I have the following configuration:

```
 container.Configure(x => {
        x.For<IAuthenticationService>().Use<AuthenticationService>();

        x.For<IDbConnectionFactory>()
                    .Use<OrmLiteConnectionFactory>().Ctor<string>("connectionString").Is("Server=(localdb)\v11.0;Integrated Security=true;")
                    .Ctor<IOrmLiteDialectProvider>("dialectProvider").Is(SqlServerOrmLiteDialectProvider.Instance);
  });
```

And in this scenario IAuthenticationServer is being instanced normally. But when i try to access DbConnection it's not injected and it's null

```
    public IDbConnectionFactory DbFactory { get; set; } //injected by IOC

    IDbConnection db;
    IDbConnection Db
    {
        get
        {
            return db ?? (db = DbFactory.Open());
        }
    }
```

That's the way i'm trying to access db. And in getter DbFactory is null. How can i fix that?

Answer (score 1):

StructureMap doesn't automatically do setter injection (by conscious design), you have to opt into it. Either change your class so that IDbConnection is injected through the constructor function (preferred), or check this out to see how to use setter injection w/ StructureMap: http://structuremap.github.io/setter-injection/